# How to get the deleted files back from a git repo

Tags: git

How to get the deleted files back when...

1. Files are `rm` ?
2. Files are `git rm` ?
3. Files are `git rm` and `git commit` ?

Answer (score 2):

### Files are `rm`

If you know which files are removed:

```
git check -- filename
```

or

```
git checkout-index filename
```

If you don't know which files are removed or there are too many removed files:

```
git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --
```

### Files are `git rm`

Use `reset` to roll back the index first

```
git reset HEAD
```

And use the commands listed above

```
git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout-index
```

### Files are `git rm` and `git commit`

If you know which commit(ex: 2ae853) you remove the files, you can checkout files from the previous commit(2ae853^) of that commit:

```
git checkout 2ae853^ -- filename
```

If you forget which commit you removed the files, use `rev-list` to find the commit first:

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- filename
```

And use the previous command to get the files back.